# Angular directive is working not for ajax loaded element

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Angular directive is not working for ajax loaded element.

Here is my code.

```
var HighlightCode = angular.module('HighlightCode', []).directive('highlight', function() { //No I18N
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // highlight code

        }
    }
});
```

if i call like this , it works.

`<p class="descriptionPara" highlight ngbind-html="parseDesc(p)" ></p>`

but this doesn't work:

`<p class="descriptionPara" ngbind-html="parseDesc(p)" >
    <pre highlight> elements </pre> // loaded from ajax parseDesc(p)
</p>`

Comment: try `restrict: 'EA'`,

Comment: the function gets call in method 1 but in method 2 it does'nt, please help. and restrict: 'EA' not working.

Comment: What is `ngbind-html` and how does it work? Doesn't seem to be a 'native' [`ngBindHtml` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Comment: If `ngbind-html` changes DOM then your `highlight` directive could not work. Why can't you use `highlight ngbind-html="parseDesc(p)"` on the same element? If it works in 1st described case.

Answer (score 0):

The element in your link function is p in the first scenario and pre in the second scenario. Did you take that into account in your code?

I guess parsedesc() is not something angular knows about. So it doesn't know the new  element is living now. Maybe use $scope.apply() somewhere to run a digest cycle.